# Bootstrap and phone orientation - form buttons positioning

Tags: css, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to position form buttons using Bootstrap responsive layout grid. That code part looks like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" name="update_cart" value="Update Totals" class="btn btn-block btn-plain" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" name="empty_cart" value="Empty Cart" class="btn btn-block btn-plain btn-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" name="next" value="Checkout" class="btn btn-block btn-plain pull-right btn-wide" />
        </div>   
      </div>    </div>
```

Based on a code above I expect to have `col-xs-` executed when phone (Samsung Galaxy S3 at that case - 720px by 1280px) in a vertical orientation and when phone is a horizontal orientation to have `col-sm-` executed, but it stays on `col-xs-`

My CSS contains (based on Boostrap Grid Options and iPad/iPhone/SGS resolutions):

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
@media (min-width: 768px)
@media (min-width: 992px)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)
@media (max-width: 1024px)
@media (max-width: 1280px)
```

Any clue why is it not switching based on a phone orientation/resolution and [grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)?

Test page: http://www.bootply.com/121024

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default values for media queries in Bootstrap are (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> ```
> col-lg-; @screen-lg: >1200px 
> col-md-; @screen-md: >992px 
> col-sm-; @screen-sm: >768px 
> col-xs-; @screen-xs: <768px
> ```

and it looks like on Samsung Galaxy S3 phone I have real "@media breakpoint" dimensions which are

```
Chrome:
360 x 567 when vertical
640 x 287 when horizontal

Android native browser:
360 x 615 when vertical
640 x 335 when horizontal
```

based on http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/

In that case I need to recompile Bootstrap with new @screen-xs set to 640px

Answer (score 0):

The default values for media queries in Bootstrap are:

- col-lg-; @screen-lg: 1200px; @media (min-width: @screen-lg) { }
- col-md-; @screen-md: 992px; @media (min-width: @screen-md) { }
- col-sm-; @screen-sm: 768px; @media (min-width: @screen-sm) { }
- col-xs-; @screen-xs: 480px; @media (min-width: @screen-xs) { }

Tha means on a Samsung Galaxy S3 phone (with 1280x720px display) you'll have:

- in vertical position: col-xs- (because: @screen-xs < 720px < @screen-sm)
- in horizontal position: col-lg- (because: @screen-lg < 1280px)

Good Luck!

Comment: Added col-lg-3 (first div), col-lg-3 (second div) and col-lg-6 (third div) and is not switching to that grid when horizontal.

Comment: Updated OP with a link to BootPlay

Answer (score 0):

As answered in a similar question 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23462633/657926

You can add your orientation specific styles like this:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9) { } // landscape 
@media (max-width: 768px) and (max-aspect-ratio: 13/9) { } // portrait.
```